# AOSP build not taking latest changes in the vendor folder

Tags: android-emulator, android-source, qemu, android-build, android-make

Replaced the files in the vendor/XXXX folder with the latest version and initiated a build(m -j8). It took less than 5 mins to complete the built.
New system images are created. However, changes are not updated in the emulator. 
However things work when I delete the out folder and try the build again. That will take 3-4 hours to complete the build.

Anyone know the reason why it didn't work the first time.

Comment: Have you tried 
make vnod
or to delete the image?

Comment: I am not sure about this vnod command...How can I use this?

Comment: make help: -> "make vnod   -  Quickly rebuild the vendor image from built packages
                            Stands for "Vendor, NO Dependencies"

Comment: Tried m vnod and it didn't work.When I launch the emulator, the version number is still the same as the previous version ..I did receive the below messages[100% 1/1] Target vendor fs image: out/target/product/generic_x86_64/vendor.img
WARNING: out/target/product/generic_x86_64/vendor.img approaching size limit (99999744 now; limit 100000000)

#### build completed successfully (6 seconds) ####